# Forming a set of cardinality from $m$ from $p$-many sets

Tags: combinatorics

Let $S_i$ for $1 \le i \le p$ be disjoint sets of cardinalities $n_i \ge 1$.

In how many ways, we can form a set $S$ of cardinality fixed $m \in \mathbb N$ by picking elements from at least two $S_i$s?

The number of such sets $S$ is counted by any familiar combinatorial numbers? Please share your thoughts. Thank you.

If $m \le n_i$ for all $1 \le i \le p$ then the problem seems relatively easy to deal with since each $S_i$ will contribute all the time. But even in this case, I couldn't get the exact count.

Comment: Are the $S_i$ disjoint?

Comment: @RobPratt Yes. Thanks. I have edited it.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the simplest case $p=2$.  Conditioning on the cardinality $k=|S \cap S_1|$ yields $$\sum_{k=1}^{m-1} \binom{n_1}{k}\binom{n_2}{m-k}
=\sum_{k=0}^m \binom{n_1}{k}\binom{n_2}{m-k} - \binom{n_1}{m} - \binom{n_2}{m}
=\binom{n_1+n_2}{m} - \binom{n_1}{m} - \binom{n_2}{m}.
$$